# Session not working on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: php

I'm on a local machine (127.0.0.1)
On login.php I create a session variable extracting value from DB

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
```

On upload.php I call variable

```
session_start();
$a = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And use variable on WHERE in a query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'");
```

Problem is, both query working well on Internet Explorer but NOT Working on Chrome and Firefox.

Any advice to solve this?

Comment: Don't know what the problem is but I suggest you start from scratch doing it the right way, preparing your queries to avoid potential sql injection. Read warning here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Youre not telling us the whole story here. Why do you post the same query twice? Also everything posted is server side (PHP) code, so browsers are irrelevant. Do you have `session_start();` in all PHP files?

Comment: var_dump $_SESSION in Chrome and verify it's not empty

Comment: show us the HTML code rather than server side.

Comment: I have checked: ["user_id"]=> string(1) "4"

Comment: Dan, this page contain only PHP code

Comment: There has to be some type of output if you are using a browser? What is allowing you to see what you variables are? echo statements?

Answer (score 0):

you should always include `session_start();` in the head of every page that uses $_SESSION - unless it will not work properly - so in login.php also put it in the head

Comment: All pages have <?php session_start(); ?> in the head

Comment: It's in the head, but is it FIRST?